# Распределение суммы на интервал

Tags: алгоритм, функции, математика, график

Всем привет!

Есть вопрос, какие есть способы для неравномерного распределения какого-то числа на определенный интервал и как это делается? Предположим, есть интервал 1 день (24 часа: 0...24), и есть число 50, минимальный интервал распределения 1 час.

По сути, если делать равномерное распределение, то достаточно 50/24 и наложить полученное число на каждый час. Получится прямая, где на каждый час приходится 2.08 или график x/24, который растет каждый час.

Суть задачи, в том, что мне нужно распределить неравномерно какое-то число на интервал. Предположим, у меня есть система выдачи задач, у нее есть каждый день какое-то фиксированное число (например, 150 задач), нужно применить какой-то метод, чтобы раскидывать эти задачи неравномерно (вид распределения пока неизвестен, но по сути должен напоминать активность пользователей в интернет в течении дня). Предположим:

1) 10 процентов с 0 до 5

2) 30 процентов с 5 до 10

3) 40 процентов с 10 до 20

4) 20 процентов с 20 до 24

Суть в этих числах не важна, это для примера. Понятно, что можно это сделать с помощью процентов и контроля времени, но может есть какой-то более умный способ, с помощью cos, sin, фукнции Гаусса.

По сути, я хочу сообщать функции, что сейчас например 12 часов дня, и уже выполненно столько, а она мне будет возвращать сколько осталось еще сделать от общего числа к текущему времени по этому распределению.

Буду благодарен любым советам, от ссылок на всякие уроки до разьяснений.

Comment: не совсем понятно что именно вы хотите сделать. Если допустимо считать что распредление равномерно внутри блока, тогда задача легко решается, но вы что-то говорили о нормальном распределении...

Comment: Хочу неравномерно распределить число на отрезок. Предположим, есть число 20 и отрезок от 1 до 5. Пример:

1 - 1;
2 - 4;
3 - 5;
4 - 2;
5 - 8;

Каким способом можно "размазать" сумму по какому-то интервалу неравномерно.

Comment: ну а если так и делать? Берем ваши задачи, допустим 50. Берем 0 час, берем рандом [0-10], полученное число пишем в 0 час, вычитаем из 50, и переходим к 1 часу?  Когда дошли до конца и задачи еще остались, проходим еще раз по тому же алгоритму, только теперь полученные рандомом числа добавляем к уже имеющимся в данном часе. Если не хотите итераций, постройте распределение, и пропорционально увеличьте каждый столбец до искомой суммы часов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта операция называется линейной интерполяцией. Формула такова:

```
y = a * x1 + (1.0 - a) * x2
```

где `x1` и `x2` - это два значения, задающие минимум и максимум, а `a = [0..1]` - коэффициент интерполяции.

Для данной задачи требуется задать `x1 = min(x)`, `x2 = max(x)` и функцию распределения `a = a(t)`, где `t` - это время.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Это то что мне нужно, буду читать про это! Может посоветуете, какую функцию надо подставить чтобы сэмулировать всплеск в середине интервала? Чтобы она работала в данном случае? Или это нужно анализировать? :)

Comment: Можно попробовать взять пилообразную функцию - `y = arcsin(sin(t))`, снизу её обработать лимитером - `y = const`, а затем сделать сглаживание с помощью интерполяции к самой себе, умноженной на 0.75 - `y = 0.75 * f(x)`. То есть `y = f(x) * 0.75 * f(x) + (1.0 - f(x)) * 0.75 * f(x))`.

Comment: Спасибо!! Буду пробовать)